# Cannot read property 'body' of null, in chrome but working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get data from a `<object>` tag using JavaScript. But while reading I get the below error in Chrome:

> Cannot read property 'body' of null

But the same code is working fine in Firefox. Below is my code:

```
<body onload="init()">
    <object id="data" data="graph.json" type="text/plain" style="display:none"></object>
</body>
<script>
var init = function(){
    var json = document.getElementById("data").contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    var graph = JSON.parse(json);
}
</script>
```

So `document.getElementById("data").contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML` gives the error.

Comment: first step is to do `console.log(document.getElementById("data"))` and then check what is the difference on both browsers.

Comment: So the difference is in chrome I am just getting empty object tag but in chrome I am getting this tag with data.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML
```

The `<object />` element will hold the html when you define source - the browser will render the html in it. So, innerHTML simply will work and you don't need to worry about contentDocument and or contentWindow. You needed this if you were using `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.contentDocument`, you could use `.contentWindow.document`, which seems to work on Chrome.

Also, I would not use `.childNodes[0].innerHTML`, but `.textContent`, because HTML may include HTML entities (like `&gt;` when your JSON has `<` somewhere), while `textContent` will just give the plain text.

So:

```
document.getElementById("data").contentWindow.document.body.textContent
```